# laravel Ajax success function not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I send a `store` request to my laravel application through AJAX. The controller function works properly, but either I cannot get a success message in my ajax function, or the function on success is not working.

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/dreams',
    data: {
        description: description,
        offset_top: offset_top,
        offset_left : offset_left
    },
    success: function(msg){
        console.log("done");
    }
});
```

Controller's `store` function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    echo $request;
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $dream = new Dream($request->all());
        if ($dream) {
            $user->dreams()->save($dream);
            $response = array(
              'dream' => $dream,
              'status' => 'success',
              'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
            );
            return \Response::json($response);
        }
        return \Response::json(['msg' => 'No model']);
    } else {
      return \Response::json('msg' => 'no auth');
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't get the `success` handler, then there is an error somewhere. Check the console. It's also possible that the AJAX request is not being made at all. Again, you need to make some effort to debug the logic. With what little information you've shown here there could be thousands of possible errors.

Comment: Try removing `echo $request;` in that first line of the store method. What happens then?

Comment: There is no error in console (php artisan serve), neither in the log file (storage/logs/laravel.log)

Comment: In the web browser console ....

Comment: @ChrisForrence It worked. It seems the problem was in `echo $request`

Comment: try to check response in Network

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass data in ajax using this way.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/dreams',
    data: {
        description: description,
        offset_top: offset_top,
        offset_left: offset_left
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log("done");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for store method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $dream = new Dream($request->all());
        if ($dream) {
            $user->dreams()->save($dream);
            $response = array(
              'dream' => $dream,
              'status' => 'success',
              'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
            );
            return \Response::json($response);
        }
        return \Response::json(['msg' => 'No model']);
    } else {
      return \Response::json(['msg' => 'no auth']);
    }
}
```